# Sonar integration test not showing up using gradle

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco, cobertura, sonarqube-scan

I'm using "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.2.1" and Jacoco report files are already created.

This is my sonarQube configuration in my build.gradle:

```
sonarqube {
    properties {
        property "sonar.host.url", "https://localhost"
        property "sonar.projectName", "Project"
        property "sonar.projectKey", "org.sonarqube:java-gradle"
        property "sonar.sourceEncoding", "UTF-8"
        property "sonar.cobertura.reportPath", "$buildDir/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml"
        property "sonar.jacoco.itReportPath", "$buildDir/jacoco/integrationTest.exec"
        property "sonar.exclusions", "**/build/**,**/thirdparty/**,**/*.properties"
    }
}
```

But the coverage still stays the same:
[image: sonarqube coverage]